# Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME Opera Browser prevent toggle menu by pressing Alt

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, appmenu, opera

When you press single <kbd>Alt</kbd> button or in combination with another key i always see this menu:

[image]

How to prevent this behavior only for Opera browser in GNOME? Because some similar behavior have another programs like Firefox, VSCode.. But in case all another known me programs they just show **File Menu** when pressed single <kbd>Alt</kbd> and don't process next button like menu item. Another difference in behavior of Opera is very sensitive response to pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Just need <kbd>Alt</kbd> key down and no mater was pressed another key in same time with <kbd>Alt</kbd> you will get menu opening in 90%.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing and holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key will universally bring up a "File, Edit..." style menu in all windows. However normally it only appears in the top bar whereas Opera is doing a giant drop down menu. For example here is how Firefox behaves when you press and hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key:

[image: Alt key press.gif]

There have been many complaints over the years about Opera's <kbd>Alt</kbd> key drop down menu:

- From 2010: [How to disable Opera alt button?](https://superuser.com/questions/151487/how-to-disable-opera-alt-button.)
- From 2013: [Alt key opens menu](https://forums.opera.com/topic/286/alt-key-opens-menu)
- From 2014: [How to disable Opera menu being open by pressing alt in opera 20+](https://forums.opera.com/topic/3799/alt-how-to-disable-opera-menu-being-open-by-pressing-alt-in-opera-20)
- From 2015: [Disable Alt Key Drop-down Menu](https://forums.opera.com/topic/12669/disable-alt-key-drop-down-menu)
- From 2015: [Anyway to hide or move the "Menu" drop-down list in the top left hand corner?](https://forums.opera.com/topic/14608/anyway-to-hide-or-move-the-menu-drop-down-list-in-the-top-left-hand-corner)
- From 2017: [Left alt key - dropdown menu](https://forums.opera.com/topic/21463/left-alt-key-dropdown-menu)
- From 2018: [Option to turn off ALT key opening main menu](https://forums.opera.com/topic/26261/option-to-turn-off-alt-key-opening-main-menu)

So far the Opera developers have ignored the pleas of these users.